# Filename converts from unicode to ascii

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, unicode, ascii

I have a django model with a unicode FileField which I serialize with django rest framework and the FileField values get converted to ascii or some other encoding which does not contain many of the characters from the filename.

All the other fields that contain Unicode characters remain the same, only the file field gets converted. I haven't seen anything about this from the docs or from stack overflow.

I have tried specifying explicitly the encoding of the serializer like: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- #, but nothing changed.
Do I need to declare the field on its own in the serializer with the correct encoding?
If so, then how?

Here is the serializer:

```
class UploadModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = models.DatauploadUploadmodel
    fields = '__all__'
```

Here is the model:

```
class DatauploadUploadmodel(models.Model):
table = models.CharField(max_length=50)
file = models.FileField(upload_to='upload_files/', max_length=200 )
user_id = models.IntegerField()
is_new_table = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
skiprows = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
status_description = models.CharField(
    max_length=100, default="Feldolgozásra vár", blank=True, null=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
upload_timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
mode = models.TextField()

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'dataupload_uploadmodel'
```

This is the view:

```
class UploadmodelList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
queryset = models.DatauploadUploadmodel.objects.all()
serializer_class = serializers.UploadModelSerializer
permission_classes = [AuthorAllUser]
```

This is how the filename looks like in the api:

> k%C3%B6lts%C3%A9gek-2022-09-091.xlsx

And this is how it looks like in the database:

> költségek-2022-09-09.xlsx

Comment: That's not ASCII, its simply url encoded. (Because well... you get a url to the file from the serializer) Many characters aren't exactly url safe so they get encoded.

Comment: How can I avoid that? How can I tell the serializer that it is fine for me?

Comment: The serializer is simply returning the URL exposed by the Django field, you can't stop the URL encoding in any way. What you could do is you could set `use_url` to `False` on the serializer field: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#filefield which will cause the serializer to return the name instead of the url. You could add 2 serializer fields for the same field if you want to show both the url and the file name.

Comment: FYI, `# coding: utf8` delcares the encoding of the *source file*.  It doesn't affect anything else.